# HighCharts/jQuery: chart.redraw slow - possible to improve speed?

Tags: jquery, highcharts

Just made a small code to change the height of panes dynamically through mouse drag. But the animation is jerky. Any solutions to make it more smoother?

Seems like the code updates the chart details and redraws simultaneously so one of the panes has older values compared to the other  one.

This [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/sandeepy02/LTgQS/4/) for demo.

**UPDATE**

Tried to use `$.when` and `$.finish` [here](http://jsfiddle.net/sandeepy02/LTgQS/5/) but still not working :(

Thanks

CODE BELOW:

```
$(function () {
    $.getJSON('http://www.highcharts.com/samples/data/jsonp.php?filename=aapl-ohlcv.json&callback=?', function (data) {

        // split the data set into ohlc and volume
        var ohlc = [],
            volume = [],
            dataLength = data.length;

        for (i = 0; i < dataLength; i++) {
            ohlc.push([
            data[i][0], // the date
            data[i][3], // open
            data[i][2], // high
            data[i][3], // low
            data[i][4] // close
            ]);

            volume.push([
            data[i][0], // the date
            data[i][5] // the volume
            ])
        }

        // set the allowed units for data grouping
        var groupingUnits = [
            [
                'week', // unit name
            [1] // allowed multiples
            ],
            [
                'month', [1, 2, 3, 4, 6]]
        ];

        // create the chart
        $('#container').highcharts('StockChart', {
            chart: {
                animation: {
                    duration: 200
                }
            },

            rangeSelector: {
                selected: 1,
                enabled: false
            },

            navigator: {
                enabled: false
            },
            scrollbar: {
                enabled: false
            },
            yAxis: [{
                title: {
                    text: 'OHLC'
                },
                height: 200,
                lineWidth: 2
            }, {
                title: {
                    text: 'Volume'
                },
                top: 200,
                height: 100,
                offset: 0,
                lineWidth: 2
            }],

            series: [{
                type: 'candlestick',
                name: 'AAPL',
                data: ohlc,
                dataGrouping: {
                    units: groupingUnits
                }
            }, {
                type: 'column',
                name: 'Volume',
                data: volume,
                yAxis: 1,
                dataGrouping: {
                    units: groupingUnits
                }
            }]
        });
    });
});
$('.rsh').draggable({
    axis: 'y',
    containment: 'parent',
    helper: 'clone',
    drag: function (event, ui) {
        var chart=jQuery("#container").highcharts();
var _redraw = chart.redraw;
chart.redraw = function(){};        
        var height1 = ui.offset.top;
        jQuery(".rsh").css("top", height1);

        chart.yAxis[0].update({
            'height': height1
        }, false);
        chart.yAxis[1].update({
            'top': height1,
            'height': 300-height1
        }, false);
chart.redraw = _redraw;
        chart.redraw();
    }
});
```

Comment: haven't tried this myself, but see http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#Chart.redraw - you may be able to override this method to a no-op as soon as you receive a resize event, and have a timer re-enable the method when no resize events have been received for a while.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just disable animations on drag, otherwise you will running 1000ms animation, starting new one each time you drag panes. Fixed solution: http://jsfiddle.net/LTgQS/6/

```
$('.rsh').draggable({
  axis: 'y',
  containment: 'parent',
  helper: 'clone',
  drag: function (event, ui) {
    var chart = jQuery("#container").highcharts();
    var height1 = ui.offset.top;
    jQuery(".rsh").css("top", height1);

    chart.yAxis[0].update({
        'height': height1
    }, false);
    chart.yAxis[1].update({
        'top': height1,
            'height': 300 - height1
    }, false);
    chart.redraw(false);
  }
});
```

Instead of using div positioned over the chart (tooltip looks weird), try to use Highcharts.Renderer to add [path](http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#Renderer.path).

Comment: Tx Pawel.Highcharts.renderer is a good idea... cleaner and easier to manipulate code too. But path.attr("path",[M,x,y,L,x1,y1]) does not modify the paths' position nor does path.d="M x y L x1 y1"

Comment: Merry Christmas ;) Try to use `path.attr({ d: "M x y L x1 y1" });`